# select function focus function and text field value is not working

Tags: javascript

```
 <input type="text" name="last" size="16 ONCHANGE ="nameselect();"> 
 function nameselect(){
if(isBlank(""+document.contest.last.value)){
document.contest.last.value = "surname"
document.contest.last.focus();
document.contest.last.select();
}

}
 function isBlank(s){
 var len = s.length;
 for(var i =0; i<len;++i){
 if(s.charAt(i)!="") return false;
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Last name: `<input type="text" name="last" size="16 ONCHANGE ="nameselect();">`
i am having text field on which onchange function is running. in this function if the text field is empty then automatically it has to set as surname and the current focus set to the field and text got selected as well but none of the applies function is working, its quite confusing for me.

Comment: Any console errors? Post some `html` too!

Answer (score 4):

The HTML is probably causing you some issues.

See that the attribute is not closed properly `size="16 ONCHANGE ="`

In your example you have

```
 <input type="text" name="last" size="16 ONCHANGE ="nameselect();">
```

it should be:

```
 <input type="text" name="last" size="16" onChange="nameselect();">
```

That should be the start at least.